# making model and migration with a single command in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I've tried this artisan command as I followed a tutorial

```
php artisan make:model Foo -m
```

but I get this error:

```
exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The "-m" option does not exist.'
```

why It's not recognizing that?
If It's a wrong way to do It , what the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, this is how you do it.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\lms>php artisan make:model Test -m
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2016_08_29_160434_create_tests_table

It must work. If that does not, do.
C:\xampp\htdocs\lms>composer install. 
and that should work.
```

Comment: so It doesn't depend on laravel's version?

Comment: I mean you are doing the right thing if you are on 5.2. Did you copy/clone an old instance of Laravel? If yes, do composer install or composer update and it should fix it. It does depend on the version, yes.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)